# Как загрузить сразу несколько файлов в django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Прошу вашей помощи с загрузкой файлов. Хочу написать типа галереи, но столкнулся с проблемой загрузки нескольких файлов. С одним файлом нет проблем, но когда я хочу загрузить несколько, то получаю ошибку:

> AttributeError at /
>   'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'save'
>   Request Method: POST
>   Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:5000/
>   Django Version: 3.0.2
>   Exception Type: AttributeError
>   Exception Value:
>   'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'save'
>   Exception Location:     /home/alex/PycharmProjects/gallery_engine/gallery_engine/gallery/views.py in create, line 12
>   Python Executable:      /home/alex/PycharmProjects/gallery_engine/venv/bin/python3
>   Python Version: 3.7.4
>   Python Path:
>   ['/home/alex/PycharmProjects/gallery_engine/gallery_engine',
>    '/usr/lib/python37.zip',
>    '/usr/lib/python3.7',
>    '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
>    '/home/alex/PycharmProjects/gallery_engine/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
>    '/home/alex/PycharmProjects/gallery_engine/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools-40.8.0-py3.7.egg',
>    '/home/alex/PycharmProjects/gallery_engine/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py3.7.egg']
>   Server time:    Thu, 23 Jan 2020 07:53:31 +0000

Уже третью неделю пытаюсь решить свою проблему разными способами, но не получается. Возможно ли это вообще сделать стандартными инструментами django?
Я новичок, не пинайте сильно пожалуйста.
Спасибо!

*views.py*

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import UploadFilesForm


# Create your views here.
def create(request):
    form = UploadFilesForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFilesForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            for f in request.FILES.getlist('files'):
                f.save()
    return render(request, 'gallery/upload_images.html', {'form': form})
```

*models.py*

```
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class UploadFilesModel(models.Model):
    files = models.ImageField(upload_to='upload', blank=True)
```

*forms.py*

```
from django import forms
from .models import UploadFilesModel



class UploadFilesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UploadFilesModel
        fields = ['files']

    files = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'multiple': 'multiple'}))
```

Comment: Эта ошибка для строки `f.save()`? Добавьте в вопрос полный стек

Comment: Полный стек, в смысле остальные файлы или определенные какие-то?

Comment: С ошибкой `'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'save'` должен быть еще текст с именами файлов, это трасса стека. По ней понятно где произошла ошибка

Comment: Таки попробуйте вызывать .save() на форме, а не файле

Comment: Если использую form.save(), то сохраняется последний файл из нескольких. Если использовать for i in form: i.save(), то получаю: 'BoundField' object has no attribute 'save'